Changing position of group/layer expand button of the LayerSwitcher control in the ol-ext library in OpenLayers?
I'm using the ol-ext library to build a LayerSwitcher.
var switcher = new ol.control.LayerSwitcher({
  target:$(".layer-switcher").get(0), 
  show_progress:false,
  extent: false,
  trash: false,
  reordering: true,
});

I would like to change the position in which the '+' and '-' buttons are shown to expand the groups or not.
As shown in image 1, it shows on the right side of the group/layer name.

I would like to change it to show as in image 2, on the left side.

What should I change in the css for this configuration?
